# Scripts folder missing in ASP.NET MVC 5 project folder

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2019

[image][image]I have created a project in ASP.NET MVC in Visual Studio 2019.

After creating the project and adding a view to the `HomeController`, I noticed that no scripts folder is added to the project.

Scripts folder is missing.

How can I restore my scripts folder?

Comment: Please post a screenshot of your project 's solution explorer

Comment: yes @Krishan . I have added the screenshots.

Comment: I am a beginner sir. Can you please tell me how to do that.

Comment: Don't Choose Empty project template. Choose ASP.NET MVC in the project Template and Tick MVC. fonts,contents,Scripts everything will be present.

Answer (score -1):

I have resolved this issue, maybe this is caused because of the VS 2019 version.

So I have to add these folders manually to work. Folders names are -

- fonts
- contents
- Scripts

Thanks for everyone who tried to help me.

Comment: Don't Choose Empty project template. Choose ASP.NET MVC in the project Template and Tick MVC. fonts,contents,Scripts everything will be present